# My first plugin doesn't save the data in options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

This is my entire code. It doesn't save the data I enter on the plugin settings page. I don't have a clue on why this happens! Can somebody please help me?

```
<?php // add the admin options page
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_admin_add_page');
function plugin_admin_add_page() {
    add_options_page(
        'Revenue Share Plugin',
        'RSP Menu',
        'manage_options',
        'RSP_plugin',
        'RSP_options_page'
    );
}
?>

<?php // display the admin options page
function RSP_options_page() {
    ?>
    <div>
    <h2>Adsense Revenue Share Plugin</h2>
    Set the publication id and the position of the ad here!
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php settings_fields('RSP_options'); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections('RSP_plugin'); ?>

    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
    </form></div>

    <?php 

    $options = get_option('RSP_options');
    echo '<br /><h4>Current Settings</h4><br>';
    echo 'Adsense Publisher Id';
    echo $options['RSP_text_string']; 
    print_r($options)
    ?>

    <?php
}?>

<?php // add the admin settings and such
add_action('admin_init', 'RSP_admin_init');
function RSP_admin_init(){
    register_setting( 'RSP_options', 'RSP_options', 'RSP_options_validate' );
    add_settings_section('RSP_main', 'Main Settings', 'RSP_section_text', 'RSP_plugin');
    add_settings_field(
        'RSP_text_string',
        'RSP Adsense Pub Id',
        'RSP_setting_string',
        'RSP_plugin',
        'RSP_main'
    );
}
?>

<?php // validate our options
function RSP_options_validate($input) {
    $options = get_option('RSP_options');
    $options['RSP_text_string'] = trim($input['RSP_text_string']);
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/i', $options['RSP_text_string'])) {
        $options['RSP_text_string'] = '';
    }
    return $options;
}
?>

<?php
function RSP_setting_string() {
    $options = get_option('RSP_options');
    echo "<input id='RSP_text_string' name='RSP_options[RSP_text_string]' size='40' type='text' value='{$options['RSP_text_string']}' />";
}
?>

<?php
function RSP_section_text() {
    echo '<p>Main description of this section here.</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I think it is a better way you sue the [settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), it is easier and fast forward. You find excellent tutorials in the www

Comment: I am using setting API! Can you help me find what I am doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Import on the settings API is the id, the string (like settings-group) there you use to identifier the data. see [tutorial](http://wpengineer.com/2139/adding-settings-to-an-existing-page-using-the-settings-api/)

Comment: Please check, if you change the first value on `register_settings`to `'RSP_options-group'`. You have the same key for group and name. Use this also on `settings_fields`.

Comment: Do I need to change it somewhere else, because still it doesn't work! :(

Comment: Also a problem, maybe only here in the copy/paste: `print_r($options)` - add a `;` on the end of line.

Comment: But still it doesn't get saved to the database or being displayed. The only thing `print_r($options)` is displaying is: `Array ( [RSP_text_string] => )`

Comment: The callback `'RSP_section_text'` is not on the source. registered on `add_settings_section`. It is important and return the data inside the form. Maybe it is a good idea, that you format the source there was readable for possible guys and dolls, the will give help and also add all of your source.

Comment: Its there already, it is the last function in the code. Also this is my entire code. The file has nothing else apart from this! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your validate function `RSP_options_validate()`. This function always a empty string.  Check your conditional statement with `preg_match`.

If you test your source without this functions, it works.

`register_setting( 'RSP_options_group', 'RSP_options', 'RSP_options_validate' );`

to

`register_setting( 'RSP_options_group', 'RSP_options' );`

Comment: Welcome. Leave always good readable source, makes so much easier to check it.